# R: a function to calculate counts of a series within a specified percentile range

Tags: r

I can get what I want using the following functions, but I would like to know any advanced ways to do what I want -- calculating counts of a series within a specified percentile range

```
age <- 0:100
tile <- quantile(age, c(0.28, 0.63))
counts <- length(age[age > tile[1] & age < tile[2]])
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "advanced way", but here's a suggestion

```
age <- 0:100
tile <- quantile(age, c(0, 0.28, 0.63, 1))
counts <- summary(cut(age, tile, include.lowest = T))
```

Comment: I was thinking about there might be a function in R can do that.

Comment: Ahh ok. I'm not aware of any. But since it's only two lines writing your own function is really simple..